# How to reorganize netcdf level by increasing order

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I got a netcdf data but with strange level sequence.
I like the level data to range from 1000, 900, 800, .. to 100
however my data shows 300, 400, 1000, 900, 800, ... 100

What's the cleanest method to reorganize this data by rising or decreasing order?

p.s. I am considering about `CDO` or `NCO`, but failed to find a good method...

Any one help me?

Comment: Can you link an nc file?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using NCO's ncpdq to reverse values in the `level` dimension, something like:

`ncpdq -a -level in.nc out.nc`

See more details and examples [here](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncpdq-netCDF-Permute-Dimensions-Quickly).